# Cert-Manager Error Fetching certificate via cloudflare dns01 challenge

Tags: kubernetes, cloudflare

I'm trying to create a wildcard cert via cert-manager for my domain.

```
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: ipa
spec:
  # Secret names are always required.
  secretName: ipa-tls
  duration: 2160h # 90d
  renewBefore: 360h # 15d
  subject:
    organizations:
      - example
  dnsNames:
    - example.com
    - '*.example.com'
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging-dns
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

But when I try this, the cert-manager pod shows the error

> E1023 21:59:17.992812       1 controller.go:158] cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Zone com. not found in CloudFlare for domain _acme-challenge.example.com." "key"="wfs/ipa-m8tgc-3507745176-457016601"

What exactly is that error?  The top level `example.com` and the wildcard `*.example.com` both go to the same IP address.

### Edit - Added Issuer yaml

```
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging-dns
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: <redacted>
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging-dns
    solvers:
      - dns01:
          cloudflare:
            email: <redacted>
            apiTokenSecretRef:
              name: cloudflare-api-key
              key: api-token
```

Comment: Can you share your `issuer` yaml?

Comment: @MariuszK. added